# How to verify number of tagName with protractor

Tags: protractor

I'm a newbie in protractor.
I've written a test with Selenium in Java and everything is OK.

But now, i need to do the same test in protractor and it driving me crazy!

I've to check the numbre of element by tagName in my page.

My code is something like this :

```
    // Click on a button
    element(by.id('e2e-idAutomate')).click();
    // Wait for the next page to be present
    var isPresent0 = EC.visibilityOf(element(by.tagName('ngx-carousel')));
    var isPresent1 = EC.visibilityOf(element(by.tagName('cmyardneo-action-button')));

    var condition = EC.and(isPresent0, isPresent1);
    browser.wait(condition, 5000);

    // Ok, here i want to chek the number of div by tagName

    // First try!
    expect<any>(element.all(by.tagName("div"))).toContain(40); 
    // Doesn't work... Fall in timeout!

    // Second try
    element.all(by.tagName("div")).then((liste) => {   //Same Problem, fall in timeout
        expect<any>(liste.length).toBe(40);   
    });
```

How can i read the liste return by the element.all?

Thanks!

Comment: Well written first question buddy. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: please show the timeout error

Answer (score 0):

For time our issue, please refer to http://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts

One issue in your code:

```
// First try!
expect(element.all(by.tagName("div")).count()).toBe(40);
// element.all().count() is to get count of found elements
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

After another tests, my problem is not about element.all
but about page change....

What i want to do is :

1. Open a first page
2. Click on a button that make à routing to a
   second page
3. check this second page

I ve done something like that :

```
describe('test of application',  function ()  {
  beforeAll( () => {
    TR.closeTabs();
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
     browser.get('/ardoise');
     browser.waitForAngularEnabled();
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.id("e2e-idAutomate"))),5000);

  });


  it('Click on the button',  () => {   // I will go on the second page
    element(by.id('e2e-idAutomate')).click();
  });

  it('Check the second page',  () => {
    // brower.sleep(5000);
    var isPresent0 = EC.visibilityOf(element(by.tagName('ngx-carousel')));
    var isPresent1 = EC.visibilityOf(element(by.tagName('cmyardneo-action-button')));    
    var condition = EC.and(isPresent0, isPresent1);
    // Here i want to be sure the second page is loaded
    browser.wait(condition, 5000);

    // Next check....
  });
});
```

And the last condition is never OK (I've checked, the two tagName are OK!!!)
It sounds like protractor hasnot seen that a routing occurs...